# XmlReader unable to connect to remote XML using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, xmlreader

I'm trying to return the latitude and longitude of a UK postcode using the service http://uk-postcodes.com (e.g. http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/G38EU.xml).

This is working great when I try visiting the URL in my browser, but whenever I try it within my ASP.NET MVC project I'm getting a 404 exception returned?

I was wondering if this is because I'm only running the code on my localhost, instead of on a remote server? If so I can just insert test values for this, but thought I'd check to see if anyone has any experience of this!

Thanks for any help,
Steven.

Please see the code below:

```
// Get the XML document
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/" + postcode + ".xml");

// Loop through the XML document
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    // Get the latitude coordinate
    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "lat"))
    {
        coordinates.Add(xmlReader.Value);
    }

    // Get the longitude coordinate
    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "lng"))
    {
        coordinates.Add(xmlReader.Value);
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for me.  Are you sure you are using a valid postcode?  
    string postcode = "KA278AA";
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/" + postcode + ".xml");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working as expected after removing the break within the while loop.

```
            var coordinates = new List<string>();
            string postcode = "KA278AA";

            // Get the XML document
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/" + postcode + ".xml");

            // Loop through the XML document
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                // Get the latitude coordinate
                if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "lat"))
                {
                    coordinates.Add(xmlReader.ReadInnerXml());
                }

                // Get the longitude coordinate
                if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "lng"))
                {
                    coordinates.Add(xmlReader.ReadInnerXml());
                }
            }
```